# R: string list in ifelse

Tags: mysql, string, r, list, if-statement

I am looking for something comparable to the "where 'var' in (...)" statement in MySQL.

My code is as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(id=10001:10030,cc1=rep(c("a","b","c"),10))
attach(data)
data$new<-ifelse(cc1=="a"|cc1=="b",1,0)
```

What is a better way to include a list of strings in the ifelse instead of using | ?

Something like: `ifelse(cc1 in ('a','b'),1,0)`

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ifelse(cc1 %in% c("a", "b"), 1, 0)
```

Or simply:

```
as.numeric(data$cc1 %in% c("a", "b"))
```

Avoid using `attach` though. It makes things messy.

Comment: Or even simpler `cc1 %in% c("a", "b")*1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer was so close, but I just couldn't find it. (attach was only used to avoid annoying data$ for this specific example) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw this one into the mix

```
> (!as.numeric(data$cc1) > 2)+0
## [1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
```